# Different databases in different part of vhosts ejabberd

Tags: multi-tenant, ejabberd

Is there a way to specify two different databases in different part of vhost??

for example if I run two vhosts on

1) port: 1234
2) port: 5678

then Can I able to change the bosh transport protocol to different ports for different tenants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot have port reserved specifically for some vhosts. Port are shared for vhost.

However, you can have a different databases for different vhost. See ejabberd documentation for reference: http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#virtual-hosting

In the following example, two vhosts are configured to use different database backends:

```
host_config:
  "example1.com":
    auth_method: odbc
    odbc_type: odbc
    odbc_server: "DSN=example1;UID=ejabberd;PWD=ejabberd"
  "example2.com":
    auth_method: odbc
    odbc_type: odbc
    odbc_server: "DSN=example2;UID=ejabberd;PWD=ejabberd"
```

Comment: Great docs. Helped a lot. Actually I was confused with the ports but I am aware of this virtual hosting. Related to ports I have a confusion. Now its clear. Thanks :)